# software search command

Tags: command-line

1. Why verifying installation of firefox "dpkg -s firefox-esr"  not just simply "dpkg -s firefox"?

[image: dpkg -s firefox-esr]

2. What is the command to check if a specific software is up-to-date or needs update?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of input/code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Have you tested my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ apt list --upgradable | grep ^firefox
```

if you have an output, then the package need upgrade. You can simulate it with:

```
$ apt-get upgrade --dry-run
```